# Php Curl Connectin timed out

Tags: php, wordpress, curl

I have worpdress plugin which communicate with my production site https://mysite.com via curl.
Here is the curl code:

```
   $vars = json_encoded(
                array(
                   //some params
                  );
   );

    $headers = array(
        'Accept: application/json',
        'Content-Type: application/json',
    );

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://mysite.com/myapi");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $vars);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);

    var_dump(curl_error($ch);
```

It works fine for all wp sites which use my plugin, but suddenly it stop working for just one site:
and curl_error() returns this:

```
Failed to connect to mysite.com port 443: Connection timed out
```

Also my plugin is not on the wordpress repository, it's placed on https://mysite.com/plugin and my plugin use hook "site_transient_update_plugins" to check for available update. This also doesn't work anymore and they don't get message about update available anymore.

So I guess that they changed something on their server which cause this problem, and I just cannot find what can cause this.

Also I am not 100% sure, but connection take about 300 s before it throw this error. And 300 s is default value for CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT.

So any suggestion what can cause this behavior will help.

Comment: I've got to ask: Are you sure that connection to the server is working? Did you try for example to telnet to the 443 port and see if it's alive?

Comment: Yeap I am 100% sure that connection to the server is workin. And as I said it works fine for all other sites, it works fine for few my wp sites on few different servers. Just it stop working for this site. So I don't know what can cause this, some settings in php.ini or something else. I am trying to replicate it but I cannot.

Comment: The error message really looks like the problem is in the connectivity, not the application layer, that's why i asked. Typically you would get the response even if something is wrong in the app. I would check the logs on the server and if you don't find anything useful I'd do a tcpdump to see if the packets are received correctly by the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you check firewall on that site. I am sure that firewall on that site is blocking trafic to IP address of your production server.

Comment: Check the DNS resolution as well. Better yet, try to ping mysite.com from the machine that is not working. Also `wget https://mysite.com:8080` (from the machine that is not working) will give you detailed error message

Comment: Yes, the problem was in firewall. They had firewall set to drop all traffic to my server. It's fixed now. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try to telnet your site to ensure the port 443 open and accessible

```
telnet mysite.com 443
```

if you got response then mean there are not issue with your firewall and Apache /web server.

**that is not only issue with firewall you should also check with your web-server that there are 443 port open or not**.